# What would be the smallest change required for the United States to purchase Greenland (time frame: 1945-2000)?

Tags: economy, alternate-history, united-states

I have heard there have been multiple instances of this happening prior to the current president's proposal. Could this have seriously happened some time in the 20th century?

Comment: The first requirement is for the United States to want it enough to offer serious money. Denmark is a rich, well-developed country; it was never desperate for cash, so that the U.S. would have to come up with a *very* motivating proposal. (Denmark was a rather unwilling German ally in WW2, but it survived with its infrastructure mostly intact, and its economy actually grew during the war.) And, of course, after 1979, when Greenland obtained self-government, the U.S. would have to deal with the sentiments of the local Greenlanders. So the question is, *how much* does the U.S. want Greenland?

Comment: Oil discovered in Greenland. Boom, done.

Comment: 1945-2000 is a wildly wide time frame encompassing vast socio-economic and technological change. The minimal reasons in 1945 will be very, very, very different from the minimal reasons in 2000. Both the U.S. and Greenland have changed vastly (not excluding the consequences of global warming). Voting to close until the OP selects a single, target year.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle, there is oil in Greenland (offshore) but it's absurdly hard to get. So not as easy as you might think. Also, why would Denmark sell it rather than keep it for itself?

Answer (score 4):

A question of politics, not economics.

In the 17th and 18th century, kings could sell land, or give them as dowry. In the 19th century, national sentiment became stronger but kings still lingered. The [Louisiana Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Purchase) was in 1803, the [Alaska Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Purchase) was in 1867.

After that there was a double standard when colonies could be traded, or conquered, but that couldn't really be done to "real" nations -- "real" as the established, non-colonized nations defined it. Look at the trouble with [Alsace-Lorraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsace-Lorraine), or how the France failed to detach the [Saar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saar_Protectorate) from Germany after WWII. By contrast, look at how [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Poland_(1945%E2%80%931989)#Border_and_population_shifts) was shifted westwards by the Soviets.

So, assuming that the US is the "Leader of the Free World" in your alternate history, the key thing would be to **convince the Greenlanders** that they want to become Americans.

- First step, in the late 40s and early 50s there are massive American bases in Greenland. To make a political statement, *dependent housing* is later built for these bases similar to the housing in Germany, just better insulated.
- Second step, the US Dollar becomes the *informal currency* in Greenland, simply because of the purchasing power of the American airmen and their families. After a few years, this is legalized. Soon the Danish Krona disappears from use.
- Third step, there is a political dispute between Greenland and Denmark which is not about independence but some other factor. A majority of Greenlanders believe that US statehood would be a better deal for them and they start a campaign.

Comment: The majority of Greenlanders would take one look at how the US generally treated indigenous populations and flip them the bird.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, quite possible. Depends on what they can negotiate and if they believe that by the 20th century, such deals would be kept.

Comment: The majority of Greenlanders would take one look at how the US generally treated indigenous populations in the *20th and 21st centuries* and flip them both birds.

Answer (score 3):

**A Greenlandic Missile Crisis**

In the immediate aftermath of WW2, the Danish Communist Party (which had been at the core of the country's anti-Nazi resistance movement, and was reasonably popular in the real world until the mid-50s) does much better in Denmark's first post-war free elections, and ends up leads the governing coalition.

With the support of the Soviet Union, the Danish Communists eventually force out their junior coalition partners and institute a one-party state, making Denmark an eastern bloc country.

By the early 60s, the USA has begun encircling the USSR with ballistic missile installations, including in Turkey (as per the run-up to our own Cuban missile crisis). The Soviet Union co-ordinates with the Danes to position nuclear weapons in Greenland, ostensibly to guard the island against invasion, but really to show to the USA that Soviet missiles pose just as much of a threat as US missiles pose to the USSR.

In the stand-off that ensues, Kennedy refuses to make the IRL quid-pro-quo of removing the missiles from Turkey, and Khrushchev stays similarly obstinate. In the end, the agreement that is reached is that the USSR will be paid off, with a huge financial payment to be made from the USA to Denmark (technically, with that money to ultimately end up in Kremlin coffers) in exchange for the transfer of sovereignty of Greenland from Denmark to the USA, and with it the removal of the missiles.

Greenland becomes a US territory, though the only settlement to take place is via the establishment of military bases.

Comment: The odds that NATO, which completely surrounds Denmark aside from the bit next to Sweden, would allow Denmark to become communist giving the Soviets another path to the Atlantic would be rather low to minimal. In the 1945 election, it had only 12.5% of the vote. In 1947, 6.8%; 1950, 4.6%, and then lower until they vanished.

Comment: @KeithMorrison I don't think it's correct to say Denmark is "completely surrounded" by NATO countries. There was only a very short stretch of sea separating the DDR from the islands of Denmark (as can be seen https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Cold_war_europe_military_alliances_map_en.png), and, of course, Sweden was a non-aligned nation. As the Cold War went on, Sweden did became a more pro-western country, but in the very early stages, it would be more accurate to call it a true neutral country.

Comment: You should look up the actual military history of Sweden. They started a secret nuclear weapons program starting in 1945 specifically to have something for deterrence to use against an invasion by the USSR (they had reached the point they could have started testing weapons by the late 1950s), and continued the mass conscription they'd had during WW2 specifically due to the threat they perceived coming from them. Their whole defence policy revolved around one threat, and it wasn't coming from the west.

Answer (score 2):

**The Danes have sold territory to the US before.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1916_Danish_West_Indian_Islands_sale_referendum

In 1917 the Danish government sold the Danish West Indies to the US for $25 million in gold.  These became the US Virgin Islands.

In your alternate timeline, the Danes see an opportunity with this agreement (which both sides had been working on intermittently for decades).  A recently independent Norway in 1917 is disputing the Danish claim to Greenland.  If Norway prevails, Denmark has nothing.  If they sell while the US recognizes their claim, they come away with profits.

Denmark adds Greenland to the territorial purchase agreement for an additional 15      million in gold.  The low price is because of the disputed nature of the claim.  For its part, Norway accepts $5 million in gold to abandon their claim.

This is inside the 20th century by 17 years (as mandated in text of question) but earlier than the 1945 start date in the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

World War 1:

- This is similar to Willk's answer, but it's what first occurred to me. Denmark is more friendly with Germany during WW1, or allied powers declare the mining of the belt to be a violation of Danish neutrality, and as a result Greenland is stripped from Denmark in the restructuring at the end of the war as punishment. https://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/denmark The US is rewarded with territorial concessions for its aid in the war. If the 1945 timeline is needed, something similar could be done at the end of WW2.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make Greenland one of the topics of [Yalta Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalta_Conference), held in February 1945. There, Churchill, Roosevelt and Stalin had decided what post-war world would look like. It is conceivable that USA would ask for control of Greenland, and not impossible that other superpowers would accede to this demand. Of course, USA would have to yield something back in return, but this would be for you to decide.

Comment: There's no reason for the US to ask for Greenland. They already had bases in Iceland, which is more useful from a monitoring of the Atlantic standpoint, and an alliance with Canada. This was before the idea of the DEW Line or its predecessors, so Greenland had absolutely nothing of value to offer.

Comment: @Keith Morrison "There's no reason" I believe is a completely different question.

Comment: no, it isn't a completely different question. The US is not simply going to ask for completely new territory for no reason, and at the time there is literally nothing in Greenland worth it for them to have.

Comment: @Keith Morrison that depends on how do we read OP's question. I just assume that US has some reason to ask for Greenland. "Why would US want Greenland" would have been even more opinion-based.